# Facebook Status Updates from C# Windows Service

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-services, social-networking

We have a few different eCommerce applications (one platform using ASP Classic, one using ASP.NET 3.5SP1, and one using ASP.NET 4.0) where we'd like to allow users to post activities to their Facebook status.  I've seen examples in .NET Web Applications, but I was hoping someone could get us pointed in the right direction to do this from a C# Windows Service (this way we can poll the data from each application and post the status updates from the same mechanism).

Thanks in advance!  Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi! You can try this post. http://webddr.net/tips-and-tricks/facebook-offline-access-step-by-step-explanation/ Did you have any luck building th windows service? I will appreciate any help. Regards,
Patricio

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/395/

Comment: Thanks Silx, but that is lacking the access token request from a service.  Any help there?

Answer (score 0):

check this : http://weblogs.asp.net/james_crowley/archive/2011/02/03/posting-to-facebook-page-using-c-sdk-from-quot-offline-quot-app.aspx

Comment: that is a nice post (some parts of the code are messed up though), but it is not working for me.